# Initialization of weak var inside @MainActor func

Tags: swift

Can somebody explain please why initializing a weak var inside a normal func gives a warning about deallocation, but if func is marked @MainActor it doesn't?

```swift
class Foo {
    private weak var test: UIViewController?

    func bar() {
        test = UIViewController() // Warning
    }

    @MainActor
    func fooBar() {
        test = UIViewController()
    }
}
```

Looking over stackoverflow

Comment: @sweeper Maybe you can explain or send valid documentation. I found nothing about this problem :)

Comment: @Sweeper Yes but sorry, I don't see what that has to do with weak reference and deallocation.

Comment: @matt Ah, I got confused because I had `-warn-concurrency` on. Didn't realise it was the "Instance will be immediately deallocated" warning. Sorry.

Comment: @Sweeper Well that is what the question is about. I want to hear how actors affect deallocation.

Comment: @matt Okay, now that I understood what the question is asking, I suspect this is just a case that the compiler didn't check. The warning *should* be emitted, and that actors have nothing to do with it. If I make `Foo` inherit from a main-actor isolated class, like `UIView`, implicitly making `Foo` main actor-isolated, the warning appears as expected.

Comment: @Sweeper Exactly so. The OP seems to me to have uncovered a bug.